# query SQL Aggregate rows inside join

Tags: sql, oracle

Table: `ID`, `Person_ID`,`Name`

Each `Person ID` can have several rows because he can have several names (first name, last name, nick name, etc..)

I have another table that contains one row per person and some other data in it

I want to join both tables into 1 row per person and in the last column to aggregate all of the person names in to one string like this: "Thomas, anderson, neo"

Something like this:

```
SELECT A.*,  
       B.PERSON_ID, 
       B.(aggregated names here) 
  FROM USERS A, USERS_NAMES B;
```

[image]

How do i do this?

Comment: Please provide some sample data rows and desired result. I can't understand what you're asking. Also, refrain from using implicit joins.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this in the following way:

```
select u.*, un.names
from users u left outer join
     (select un.person_id, listagg(un.name, ',') within group (order by un.id) as names
      from users_names un
      group by un.person_id
     ) un
     on u.person_id = un.person_id;
```

Note that the list aggregation is being done in a subquery.  That allows the use of `u.*` in the outer query with no aggregation.  Otherwise, you have to `group by` each column in `users` explicitly.

Comment: I like the logic, voted up. But will it affect a perfomance, comparing to without-subquery-option ?

Comment: @Alexander . . . The impact on performance is probably negligible because you are selecting all the rows.  It could be better, it could be worse.  Without the subquery, you end up aggregating on many more columns.